# jQuery missing ; before statement

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery, my code looks ok, but I'm getting an error, which sounds like this:

> missing ; before statement
>   [Break on this error] }elseif($('.v_gallery li:first').hasClass('s')){\n

And my code looks like this:

> _gallery_pag : function() {
>         $('#top_pag a').live('click',function() {                                   var _type = $(this).attr('rel');
>
> ```
>         switch(_type)
>         {
>             case '1':
>                 if($('.v_gallery li:last').hasClass('s'))
>                 {
>                     $('.v_gallery li:first').find('a').click();
>                 }elseif($('.v_gallery li:first').hasClass('s')){
>                     alert('You can\'t go back!You are at the first page!');
>                 }
>             break;
>         }
>         return false;
>     });     
> }
> ```

I know, probably I miss spell checked something...because I don't see any problems.

10x guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote elseif instead of "else if" - in javascript, those are two different keywords.

here is your fixed code:

```
_gallery_pag : function() {
$('#top_pag a').live('click',function() { var _type = $(this).attr('rel');

                switch(_type)
                {
                        case '1':
                                if($('.v_gallery li:last').hasClass('s'))
                                {
                                        $('.v_gallery li:first').find('a').click();
                                }else if($('.v_gallery li:first').hasClass('s')){
                                        alert('You can\'t go back!You are at the first page!');
                                }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
        });             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you misspelled else if. Add a space between else and if.

Answer (score 1):

"elseif" isn't a keyword in JavaScript, it should be "else if"